# Dynamical search-function to show/hide divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is my first post on StackOverflow. I hope it doesn't go horribly wrong.

```
<input type="Text" id="filterTextBox" placeholder="Filter by name"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/events.js"></script>
<script>
$("#filterTextBox").on("keyup", function () {
    var search = this.value;
    $(".kurssikurssi").show().filter(function () {
        return $(".course", this).text().indexOf(search) < 0;
    }).hide();        
});

</script>
```

I have a javascript snippet like this on my school project, which can be found here: http://www.cc.puv.fi/~e1301192/projekti/tulos.html

So the search bar at the bottom is supposed to filter divs and display only those, that contain certain keyword. (t.ex, if you type Digital Electronics, it will display only Divs that contain text "Digital Electronics II" and "Digital Electronics". Right now, if I type random gibberish, it hides everything like it's supposed to, but when I type in the beginning of a course name, it will not hide the courses that dont contain the certain text-string.

Here is an example that I used (which works fine): http://jsfiddle.net/Da4mX/

Hard to explain, but I hope you realize if you try the search-function on my page. Also, I'm pretty new to javascript, and I get the part where you set the searchbox's string as var search, the rest I'm not so sure about.

Please help me break down the script, and possibly point where I'm going wrong, and how to overcome the problem.

Comment: There are some errors in console: request to http://www.cc.puv.fi/resources/events.js returned 404 and "Uncaught TypeError: targetDiv.getAttribute is not a function".

Comment: This is referring to another function that counts the course credits, which is working fine. Could this be the reason of search function not working?

Comment: Maybe; try to fix it and see if search function works.

Comment: You are accessing the wrong child elements in that case. I will try to find the correct children to be shown, give me a second, I will try to post an answer shortly

Answer (score 2):

in your case I think you show and hide the parent of courses so you can try

```
$("#filterTextBox").on("keyup", function () {
    var search = $(this).val().trim().toLowerCase();
    $(".course").show().filter(function () {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) < 0;
    }).hide();        
});
```

Comment: Thank you everybody, I managed to get it working! I thought that it should be a problem within the divs, as they were differently constructed on the example, but couldn't locate the problem. Now I only need to make it non-case-sensitive, but I'll get to that after my exam :) Have a nice day

Comment: @Hexal Good Luck in your exam :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this this is working now, paste this code in console and check, by searching.

```js
$("#filterTextBox").on("keyup", function () {
    var search = this.value;  if( search == '') { return } 
 $( ".course" ).each(function() {
   a = this; if (a.innerText.search(search) > 0 ) {this.hidden = false} else {this.hidden = true}
 }); })
```

Check and the search is now working.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is there :

```
return $(".course", this)
```

From jquery doc: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selection

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
>   so  $( "span", this ) is equivalent to  $( this ).find( "span" )

filter function already check each elements
then, when you try to put $(".course") in context, it will fetch all again...

Valid code :

```
$("#filterTextBox").on('keyup', function()
{
    var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".course").show().filter(function()
    {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) < 0;
    }).hide();
});
```

In fact, you can alternatively use :contains() CSS selector,
but, it is not optimized for a large list and not crossbrowser

http://caniuse.com/#search=contains

Answer (score -1):

You were accessing the wrong elements. This should be working:

```
$(".kurssikurssi").find('.course').show().filter(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
      if($this.text().indexOf(search) < 0){
              $this.hide()
      }
 })
```